# create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django

I'm using Django and allauth trying to get a signup page working but for some reason it does not work.

Whenever I have entered all the sign up data that's required and press Create an account it gives me this error;

TypeError at /accounts/signup/
create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

This is my signup script;

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <section class="mb-4">
        <div class="row wow fadeIn">
          <div class='col-6 offset-3'>
            <h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>
            <p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
            <form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form|crispy }}
              {% if redirect_field_value %}
              <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
              {% endif %}
              <button class='btn btn-primary' type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
{% endblock %}
```

---

Update: I'm unable to find where the problem is located at.

I have found something like this down here but I don't think that's the issue.

```
def userprofile_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
if created:
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(
        userprofile_receiver, user=instance)
```

post_save.connect(userprofile_receiver, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

Comment: Please provide the full traceback for the exception. What you have posted is a Django template, not the relevant Python code that raises the exception.

Comment: Hi, my apologies about the super late reply, some other things got in the way. But I'm unable to find the code that might be causing it. Something I found looks like this;
(This most likely isn't it)
def userprofile_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(
            userprofile_receiver, user=instance)


post_save.connect(userprofile_receiver, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)